# Django search mechanism with different views depending on search options

Tags: django, search, django-views

I try to implement search mechanism in Django but I couldn't figure out what is the best way to do it.

I have a combobox and a textbox as seacrh parameters. There are two options in combobox like "A" and "B" and depending on that option different views should be run.

However, because there is a common properties of these two options, such as `min-max length of textbox` and soon on, I consider when search button clicked, it should go to some common `search view` and after the textbox is validated,or not, depending on the option in the combobox proper page should be redirected to proper page with the request given.

**main/views.py**

```
def search(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    type = request.POST['searchType']
    searchvalue = request.POST['searchvalue']
    if len(searchvalue) > 200:
        return render_response(request, 'search/error.html', {'message':'bidi'})

    if type == 'A':
        return redirect('/A/search/')
    elif type == 'B':
        return redirect('/B/search/')
    else:
        return render_response(request, 'search/error.html', {'message':'errormessa'})
```

**A/views.py**

```
def search(request):
...
```

**B/views.py**

```
def search(request):
...
```

However, as you see, while I redirect to `view A` or `view B` I need to pass `searchvalue` as a post paramater but I couldn't do.

Besides, I wonder is my structure proper and secure way to do such search ? What is the best approach to implement such search ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know javascript, do the search(form submit?) from javascript; so basically you check what the user has chosen and suitably chose the endpoint.